# Does MembershipUser "GetUser()" call the overloads WITH parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

So I am looking at a project with some sample code.

And the website's master page calls MembershipUser.GetUser();--casts it to a custom type.

In the CustomMembershipProvider.cs class provided, the original programmers, wrote override functions for GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline), and GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline).

But they never wrote an override for GetUser() with zero or default empty parameters..... ???

So you would assume, that GetUser only brings back properties of MembershipUser, but it brings back the data written in the custom overrides instead---how is this possible?

The only explanation I have, is that MembershipUser.GetUser() default functionality, calls overrides GetUser(username,userIsOnline) or GetUser(providerUserKey,userisOnline). But this is not documented anywhere.

Is that correct? Because no where in the sample code can I find this GetUser() override, and the GetUser()s that are overridden don't have default parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

From Reflector

```
public static MembershipUser GetUser()
{
    return GetUser(GetCurrentUserName(), true);
}
```

Comment: Nice find, I wonder where I can find this stuff. Also, from where does it get the current Username? I only give it the current user ID.